# Redirect a single URL to the same URL on another domain

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I'm trying to set up my .htaccess file to take the displayed link and route it to the destination link as below

Displayed Link
`http://www.my-website.com/click-4559226-10388358?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdestination-website2.com%2FItem.php%3Fid%3D44350396%26sld%3DA6D7A632-821E-4b78-ACD0-147658B77BD6`

Destination Link
`http://www.destination-website.com/click-4559226-10388358?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdestination-website2.com%2FItem.php%3Fid%3D44350396%26sld%3DA6D7A632-821E-4b78-ACD0-147658B77BD6`

Effectively, all that changes is the first URL (`http://www.my-website.com`) everything after that is the same.

Is this possible and could someone briefly explain how I would go about it?

*** Just to be clear, I don't want to redirect everything from `my-website.com`. Just links that start `http://www.my-website.com/click-4559226-10388358`

Comment: What would have been useful, in order to better answer this question, is whether the source and destination websites are actually hosted at the same place/directory or whether they are different servers? Also, is there a requirement to use mod_rewrite? Is mod_rewrite already being used in other parts of the script?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If it's not keeping the query string, try changing the last line of the code above to

```
RewriteRule / http://www.newdomain.com/?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

**edit:**

If you only want to limit the rule to `www.my-website.com/click-4559226-10388358`, then try changing the last line of the code above to this:

```
    RewriteRule ^click\-([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)$ http://www.newdomain.com/click-$1-$2?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to redirect everything from `my-webiste.com`. Just links that start `http://www.my-website.com/click-4559226-10388358`

Comment: See the **edit** above

Comment: Even the edit looks far too general... why redirect `/click-0-0` and `/click-1-1` when the OP has specifically stated they only want to redirect `/click-4559226-10388358`? There is no need to escape hyphens in a regex that are outside of a character class. There is also no need to manually append the `%{QUERY_STRING}` onto the substitution if you aren't already specifying a query string on the substitution. The query string is copied by default.

Answer (score 1):

> Just links that start `http://www.my-website.com/click-4559226-10388358`

To redirect just the links where the URL-path is (exactly) `/click-4559226-10388358` to the *same* URL on another domain, whilst maintaining the query string, then you can do something like the following in the .htaccess file in the document root.

This uses mod_rewrite, and should come near the top of the file if you have other directives:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^click-4559226-10388358$ http://www.destination-website.com/$0 [R=302,L]
```

If the source and destination domains are located on different servers then you can omit the `RewriteCond` directive.

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. Permanent redirects are cached by the browser and so can cause problems when testing.

Answer (score 1):

If all that's changing is the query string, it should be possible to do this without `mod_rewrite`. Using a straightforward `Redirect` directive is more efficient, and often significantly faster than regular expression matching with a `RedirectRule`. Here's the `Redirect` statement, in an `.htaccess` file in the root of your site:

```
Redirect /click-4559226-10388358 http://www.destination-website.com/click-4559226-10388358
```

As w3d has pointed out, you should test that before changing to a permanent redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /click-4559226-10388358 http://www.destination-website.com/click-4559226-10388358
```

`Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` will pass the query string along to the target url unchanged.

Comment: A mod_alias `Redirect` requires a slash prefix on the _URL-path_ (origin URL) regardless of whether it is used in .htaccess or the server config. (Removing the directory-prefix is just a mod_rewrite thing.) It's perhaps worth mentioning that you should never mix redirects from both mod_alias and mod_rewrite (risk of conflict), so whilst mod_alias is more efficient, if you are already using mod_rewrite you should probably stick with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thanks @w3d: I've updated the answer now. The relevant docs are [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#page-header) if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 0):

On www.my-website.com:

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.destination-wabsite.com/
```

Comment: This redirects _everything_ - which is not the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming mod_rewrite is enabled on your server, you would want to put something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my-website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.destination-website.com/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will redirect any requests to www.my-website.com to www.destination-website.com. The [NC] tells Apache to operate in case insensitive mode and the [QSA,L] tells it to maintain any querystring parameters and that no other rules should be followed. More information can be found on [Apache's website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: This redirects _everything_ - which is not the requirement. The `QSA` flag is unnecessary here. Any query string on the request will be copied across by default providing there is no query string on the substitution (which there isn't in this case). The `<IfModule>` container is also unnecessary, since this code is dependent on mod_rewrite being enabled - it is better to fail _loudly_, rather than _silently_ in this case.